# Do $((p_1,Y_1),\ldots,(p_m, Y_m))$ and $((p_{\sigma(1)},Y_{\sigma(1)}),\ldots, (p_{\sigma(m)},Y_{\sigma(m)}))$ have the same probability distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, permutations

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d random variables taking values in $\mathcal X$ which is partitioned into $m$ clusters $\mathcal X_1, \ldots, \mathcal X_m$. Consider $((p_1, Y_1), \ldots, (p_m, Y_m))$ in which

- $p_i = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{X_j \in \mathcal X_i}$, i.e., the proportion of elements in $\mathcal X_i$.
- $Y_i = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j \mathbf{1}_{X_j \in \mathcal X_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{X_j \in \mathcal X_i}}$, i.e., the average of elements in $\mathcal X_i$.

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $(1, \ldots, m)$.

> Is it true that $((p_1, Y_1), \ldots, (p_m, Y_m))$ and $((p_{\sigma(1)}, Y_{\sigma(1)}), \ldots, (p_{\sigma(m)}, Y_{\sigma(m)}))$ have the same probability distributions?

---

I try a simple case in which $X_1, \ldots,X_n \sim \operatorname{Uniform}([0,3])$, $\mathcal X_1 = [0,2]$, and $\mathcal X_2 = [2,3]$.

We have $\mathbb P [p_1 = 0] = (1/3)^2=1/9$ and $\mathbb P [p_1 = 1/2] = \mathbb P [p_1 = 1] = 4/9$.

It follows from $p_2 = 1-p_1$ that $\mathbb P [p_2 = 0] = \mathbb P [p_2 = 1/2] = 4/9$ and $\mathbb P [p_2 = 1] = 1/9$.

As a result, there is an asymmetry between $(p_1, p_2)$ and $(p_2, p_1)$. Then I think $((p_1, Y_1), \ldots, (p_m, Y_m))$ and $((p_{\sigma(1)}, Y_{\sigma(1)}), \ldots, (p_{\sigma(m)}, Y_{\sigma(m)}))$ do **not** necessarily have the same probability distribution.

---

Could you please elaborate on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $Y_i$ correctly defined (it is $\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_j\in\mathcal{X}_i} = 1$)? If it is the average, shouldn't it be

$$ Y_i = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j 1_{X_j\in\mathcal{X}_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n 1_{X_j\in\mathcal{X}_i}}?$$

How is it defined, if $X_j\notin \mathcal{X}_i$ for all j?

Anyway, I think your example is a valid counter example. For your example it holds that $\mathbb{P}\left( Y_2\ge 2\right) \ge 1 - \mathbb{P}\left( p_2=0\right)>0$, while $\mathbb{P}\left(Y_1\ge 2\right) = 0$. Thus for the permutation $\sigma(1)=2$ and $\sigma(2)=1$ they are not identically distributed.

Comment: Sure $\{\mathcal X_1, \ldots, \mathcal X_m\}$ is a partition of $X$. I dont see how your $Y_i$is different than mine.

Comment: In the denominator you sum up over $i$, not over $j$.

Comment: You're right. Thank you so much!